# CSS3 Animation Delay longer than Duration breaks animation

Tags: css, animation

I am attempting to animate an element from `display:none;opacity:0;` to `display:block;opacity:1;`. While the below animation works, when I introduce a delay into the animation I find I cannot set the delay value higher than the animation duration value. When I do, the animation is ignored.

How do I set my delay to take e.g. 2 seconds and my animation duration to be 300ms without it breaking?

```css
    div p + p {
      display: none;
      opacity: 0;
    }  
    div p:hover + p {
      display: block;
      opacity: 1;
      /* browser prefixes removed for brevity */
      -webkit-animation: fadeInFromNone 300ms 900ms linear;
      animation: fadeInFromNone 300ms 900ms linear;
    }
    div.working p:hover + p {
      display: block;
      opacity: 1;
      /* browser prefixes removed for brevity */
      -webkit-animation: fadeInFromNone 300ms 300ms linear;
      animation: fadeInFromNone 300ms 300ms linear;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
      0% {
        display: none; 
        opacity: 0;
      }
      1% {
        display: block ; 
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        display: block ; 
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
    keyframes fadeInFromNone {
      0% {
        display: none; 
        opacity: 0;
      }
      1% {
        display: block ; 
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        display: block ; 
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div>
      <p>Hover on me (broken)</p>
      <p>Peek-a-boo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="working">
      <p>Hover on me (working)</p>
      <p>Peek-a-boo</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why am I using an animation for opacity when I could use a transition? My main reason for doing an animation was to get display:block/none to work, but in my other answer it still doesn't work as I want it to. In this answer I am using `visibility:hidden/visible` and `opacity:0/1` for the animation. The transition is so on hover that the transition takes 1 second to start (note `transition-delay` on the hover code), while on mouse-out the opacity will fade out first over nearly a second and the visibility will just stop being visible BUT it has a delay of the same amount as the opacity duration.

This gives me the lovely delayed fade-in / immediate fade-out that I wanted.

```css
div p + p {
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /* browser prefixes removed for brevity */
  transition:visibility 0s linear 900ms, opacity 900ms linear;
}
div p:hover + p {
  visibility:visible;
  opacity:1;
  /* browser prefixes removed for brevity */
  transition-delay:1s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hover on me</p>
  <p>Peek-a-boo</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to a timing issue.

Initially the p has `display:none;` and `opacity:0;`. On hover the p has `display:block;` and `opacity:1;`, and then, after the delay, this is reset to `display:none;` and `opacity:0;` when the animation starts.

By setting the hover p to have `display:block;` and animating only the opacity, then I almost get the desired result. To stop the animation from completing and setting the p as `opacity:0` again I add the `forwards` attribute to the animation:

```css
div p + p {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}  
div p:hover + p {
    display: block;
    /* browser prefixes removed for brevity */
    -webkit-animation: fadeInFromNone 300ms linear 900ms forwards;
    animation: fadeInFromNone 300ms linear 900ms forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}
keyframes fadeInFromNone {
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<div>
      <p>Hover on me</p>
      <p>Peek-a-boo</p>
    </div>
```